# Port RTOS package to embedded linux

Tags: c, openwrt, rtos, bsp

I'm new to RTOS and Embedded Linux. As I described in the title, if I want to port Zephyr's bluetooth package to OpenWrt, what are the necessary steps I have to do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Openwrt have a good documentation check this link https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/devel/packages https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/packages

Comment: Why would you not use OPenWRTs existing bluetooth support: https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/usb.bluetooth? The architectures and driver models probably differ significantly, making porting significantly hard work.

Comment: @Clifford, it is because OpenWrt is using BlueZ which uses too much memory and has large code size, I want to minimize the code size and mem use.

Comment: If code size is really the issue, then you'd be far better off using Zephyr itself rather than Linux, the size of the Bluetooth stack is unlikely to be significant amongst the typical minimal Linux requirement of 16 MB of RAM and 4 MB of Flash.   By the time you have ported the Zephyr implementation and added all the baggage needed to integrate with the Linux driver model you may even find that it is no smaller.